# Unable to consume WCF method from android

Tags: c#, android, wcf

This is my first time that I use WCF and Android. So, sorry for maybe easy question :)
This is from wcf service library:

```
[ServiceBehavior]
    public class CheckInService : ICheckInService
    {
        public string Hello()
        {
            return "Message from WCF!";
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICheckInService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "POST",
            UriTemplate = "Hello",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string Hello();
    }
```

This is from wcf service web site Service.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="TYT.Service.CheckInService"  %>
```

This is app.config from wcf service library project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TYT.Service.CheckInService">
        <endpoint address="publicService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TYT.Service.ICheckInService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TYT.Service/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

This is web config from wcf service web site:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TYT.Service.CheckInService">
        <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="TYT.Service.ICheckInService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

ANDROID CODE

```
private final static String SERVICE_URI = "http://10.0.2.2/tytservice/Service.svc";    
try {



            // Send GET request to <service>/GetPlates
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SERVICE_URI + "/Hello");
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

            // Read response data into buffer
            char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
            InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            reader.read(buffer);
            stream.close();

            String data = new String(buffer);
```

But in data string all I get is the whole HTML document with following error:

```
<span><H1>Server Error in '/tytservice' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
            <br><br>

            <b> Requested URL: </b>/tytservice/Service.svc/Hello<br><br>
...
</html>
<!-- 
[EndpointNotFoundException]: There was no channel actively listening at &#39;http://vlada-nb/tytservice/Service.svc/Hello&#39;. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
[HttpException]: There was no channel actively listening at &#39;http://vlada-nb/tytservice/Service.svc/Hello&#39;. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
-->
```

When I navigate in browser to `http://localhost/tytservice/Service.svc` I get service description but if I add `http://localhost/tytservice/Service.svc/Hello` I again get 404.
It seams that this method is not exposed but I can't figure what I missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
WebInvoke(
    Method = "POST",
```

You're calling the method with HTTP GET, not POST:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SERVICE_URI + "/Hello");
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
// ...
```

You can fix this by changing your method to `Method = "GET"`, or using an [`HttpPost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) to call it.

Also check out this related question:

- [WebInvoke Method=“POST” or "GET" for a REST Service on WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197956/webinvoke-method-post-or-get-for-a-rest-service-on-wcf)